# Pandas GroupBy Define with two DataFrames in Custom Function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a look-up-table (LUT) DataFrame that structurally resembles the follow:

```
ID    Date         ColOne
AAAA  2010-07-06   ...
AAAA  2011-12-31   ...
AAAA  2013-02-15   ...
AAAA  2015-05-21   ...
AAAB  2008-01-08   ...
AAAB  2010-10-20   ...
AAAB  2014-03-31   ...
...
```

For thousands of IDs.  I have data contained in another DataFrame (REF) that I would like to efficiently fold into the LUT above.  Structurally, REF resembles:

```
ID    Date         RefVal
AAAA  2009-01-01   Val1
AAAA  2013-05-21   Val2
AAAB  2009-03-02   Val3
AAAB  2012-09-09   Val4
AAAB  2013-12-31   Val5
...
```

In particular, I would like to place RefVal values in REF into LUT based upon values appearing dates in REF and LUT for each ID.  For example the resulting LUT might look something like:

```
 ID    Date        ColOne  RefVal
AAAA  2010-07-06   ...       Val1
AAAA  2011-12-31   ...       Val1
AAAA  2013-02-15   ...       Val1
AAAA  2015-05-21   ...       Val2
AAAB  2008-01-08   ...       NaN
AAAB  2010-10-20   ...       Val3
AAAB  2014-03-31   ...       Val5
```

In other words, the ReFVal in LUT would be the RefVal most recently reported for that ID.  A bit more explanation:

- Val1 appears three times since the next entry in REF has a date following the first three entries for AAAA;
- Val2 only appears for the last entry since that is the only entry for which the date follows the Val2's date in REF for AAAA;
- NaN appears in the first row for AAAB since there is no RefVal with a date preceding the first entry in LUT;
- Val4 never appears since there are no dates following Val4's date prior to Val5's date for AAAB.

I believe that a custom function can be defined and applied to LUT using something like:

```
LUT['RefVal'] = LUT.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: fun(x))
```

But I'm not sure how to write that function since it must reference another DataFrame and use the ID that I am grouping by.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ordered_merge` function may be what you're after:

```
df1.sort('Date', ascending=False)
df2.sort('Date', ascending=False)
res= pd.ordered_merge(df1, df2, fill_method='ffill')
```

Results in:

```
      ID       Date  ColOne RefVal
0   AAAA 2009-01-01     ...   Val1
1   AAAA 2010-07-06     ...   Val1
2   AAAA 2011-12-31     ...   Val1
3   AAAA 2013-02-15     ...   Val1
4   AAAA 2013-05-21     ...   Val2
5   AAAA 2015-05-21     ...   Val2
6   AAAB 2008-01-08     ...   Val2
7   AAAB 2009-03-02     ...   Val3
8   AAAB 2010-10-20     ...   Val3
9   AAAB 2012-09-09     ...   Val4
10  AAAB 2013-12-31     ...   Val5
11  AAAB 2014-03-31     ...   Val5
```

Comment: Great idea @crow_t_robot!  I worked out a solution that uses your result below.  It works for my example above, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to approach it.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggested answer:

```
df1 = LUT.set_index(['ID','Date']).copy()
df2 = REF.set_index(['ID','Date']).copy()
merged = pd.concat([df1a, df2a]).sort()
merged = merged.reset_index()
```

Now apply a ffill lambda as follows:

```
merged['RefVal'] = merged.groupby('ID')['RefVal'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
LUT['RefVal'] = merged.loc[LUT.index,'RefVal']
```

Any thoughts?